# upload .txt file to server using HttpRequest in Qt

Tags: qt

I hava a problem of uploading .txt file to my java servlet server using Qt.

I spent 5 days on that and tried a lot of solutions. But none of them worked.  Does anyone can help me?

**The problem is that the Qt code can work without error. But the server didn't receive anything by the httprequest from Qt.**

This is one solution in Qt:

```
QFile file("dataToSend.txt");
nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
             this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));
QNetworkRequest r(QUrl("http://localhost:9999/server"));

QString bound="---------------------------723690991551375881941828858";
QByteArray data(QString("--"+bound+"\r\n").toAscii());
data += QString("--" + bound + "\r\n").toAscii();
data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""+file.fileName()+"\"\r\n";
data += "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n";
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
data += file.readAll();
data += "\r\n";
data += QString("--" + bound + "\r\n").toAscii();
r.setRawHeader(QString("Content-Type").toAscii(),QString("multipart/form-data; boundary=" + bound).toAscii());
r.setRawHeader(QString("Content-Length").toAscii(), QString::number(data.length()).toAscii());

reply = nam->post(r,data);
reply=nam->get(r);
```

This is another solution, it is not wokring neither:

```
nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));
QFile *file=new QFile("dataToSend.txt");
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://localhost:9999/server"));
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/octet-streamd");

if(!file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
   qDebug("%s\n",qPrintable("can't open the file!"));
   return;
}

// post data to server
reply= nam->post(request,file);
file->setParent(reply);
reply=nam->get(request);
```

Comment: what do you expect by these lines : `reply= nam->post(request,file);
   file->setParent(reply);
   reply=nam->get(request);`  ?

Comment: When you say "didn't receive anything", do you mean no connection or the servlet does not receive data? Are you sure of your servlet?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot `post()` something to a server and a line below do a `get()` expecting to see the file. 
Usually you have to post, wait until `post` is finished, and than you can see modification..
[here](https://www.google.it/search?ix=heb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=upload%20file%20QNetwork%20access%20manager#sclient=psy-ab&hl=it&source=hp&q=example%20uploading%20file%20QNetworkaccessmanager&oq=example%20uploading%20file%20QNetworkaccessmanager&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=2851l4669l3l4860l2l2l0l0l0l0l183l183l0.1l1l0&gs_l=serp.3...2851l4669l3l4860l2l2l0l0l0l0l183l183l0j1l1l0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=30a123b4a57c228&ix=heb&biw=1680&bih=894) there are lots of link you can use to do things right